# Max length of attachment field

Tags: slack-api, slack

I know that attachments can be short:true or short:false, but it seems to me that even when they're short:false there is still a maximum length which is shorter than the regular length of a message.

Can this be controlled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but it was high on my GOOG results today, so thought I'd post my solution here.

Short version - I stopped using attachments and put everything in the text.

Long version - my use case was using the color-bar on attachments to display info/warn/error info, but ultimately the line-wrap was making it less useful.  The alternative is to set the sender name and icon_emoji to indicate that info, and simply put the log data in the text.  For my case, we don't have log data longer than the 4k limit, or else I'd use a files.upload approach to get text snippets.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You mean character width? This seems to be 78 characters (80 less 2 characters for the coloured bar?)

Unfortunately *no*, you do not seem to be able to change the width (at time of writing). You can resort to `text` which is full width.

`short` is for side by side fields only, not the entire attachment.

Also see [Slack Attachment Width and Wrapping Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38595363/516748)

Comment: OK, thanks.
Is there any way of adding text after the attachments? Currently, I'm splitting my text into 2 messages - the first is nicely formatted and the seconds is the "wall-o-text"

Comment: Not that I have seen. I ended up replacing my "wall-o-text" with a link so the message became nice and manageable again

Comment: @Robert Barron yes. If you add another attachment with a `pretext` field it will be displayed as standard message text.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken you can do it but then you have the limit of characters in `pretext` field.